# Nmap not working as a root

Tags: nmap, sudo, metasploitable

Hi I asked this questions on other forums, and searched on google, but nothing was useful to me. My problem works as a non-privileged used, but whenever I run it as a root, I get:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-25 16:21 CEST
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.26 seconds
```

I am working on a project, that is exploiting services and so on on vulnerable systems, such as Metasploitable. I would very much like it if someone could help me

Comment: Why do you need nmap to run as root?

Comment: it shows more ports, it performs two different searches based on whether it is as a root or not

Comment: Ah interesting. Are you attempting to use `sudo` or logged in as root?

Comment: logged in as root

Comment: you cat try `strace nmap localhost` to see where it breaks.

Comment: When you say it is not working as a root, does it mean it shows you open ports when run as non-root on the same host as target?

Comment: @void_in yup, exactly!

Comment: Are you performing this internally or externally? Have you tried as suggested by nmap using the `-Pn` option? That way it will scan the host omitting whether it's aliver or not, many firewalls will block ping probes. I had this issue before when running a scan internally and the `-Pn` option solved it.

Comment: Yes it gives the same result if I use it with '-Pn', like a non-privileged user gives when called with nmap -p0-65535 <IP-ADDRESS>, I have no idea what those options mean though, I tried finding them in the website, but I couldn't..do you know what they mean? Are they equivalent to the '-Pn'

Comment: `-p 0-65535` is telling nmap to scan all the ports, it's an option to specify the range. `-p0-` doesn't exist `-Pn` is to treat all hosts as alive, -p is to specify a specific port or a list of specific ports, such as `--top-ports <n>` or `--exclude-ports <port ranges>` to exclude a number of ports.

Comment: There are plenty of ways in which you can perform host discovery, all of them come under `-P` option. for example `-PU` will perform host discovery using UDP payload, more detailed information can be seen here [nmap-man-host-discovery](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html). Using `-Pn` is advised when you are sure that host is up and want to perform scan directly.

Comment: what's the exact command you are running?

Comment: Oh, maybe try with `-P0`

Comment: Instead of button-mashing different options to try to get something to work, use the debug output to see exactly what's going on: `nmap -d <whatever options> <target>`. If you suspect a routing problem, use `nmap --route-dst <target>` to see what Nmap thinks it should be doing. Also try `nmap --iflist` to see what Nmap thinks you have for network interfaces. But asking for help without `-d` output is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1):

Nmap uses different scanning methods depending on whether it's running as root or not.

The error you see is normal. Try adding -Pn and you will probably get identical results to the scan you ran as a regular user.

Comment: Furthermore, you could manually specify the scan type in order to force the expected behavior.